# I implemented a quicksort in Java and it works properly but i dont understand the second swap in the partition function?

Tags: java, quicksort, swap, partition

```
    private static int partition(int[] array,int links, int rechts) 
    {
        int pivotelement = array[links];  //pivotelement on the left
        int i = links;                    // links means leftside
        int j = rechts;                   // rechts means rightside
                                         
        while (i <= j) 
        {
            if (array[i] <= pivotelement) 
            {
                i++;
            }
            else if (array[j] > pivotelement)
            {
                j--;
            }
            else
            {
                swap(array,i,j);   **//first swap makes sense to me**
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        swap(array,links,j);    **//Here is the second swap. Im not sure about that but it works**.
        return j;
    }
    
    public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
```

## **Im expecting a explanation of the second swap. Why is it necessary?**

I found out that in a sorted list i dont need the second swap. Sorry thats my first Question in Stack Overflow. When you need more Information just ask for it.

These are the  arrays i try it with and it works.

```
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int[] array = {4,7,4,6,8,2,3,4,6,2};
    int[] array = {8,4,6,3,7,1,0,9,5,22};
    int[] array = {1};
```

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Either on paper, or with a debugger? Take one example, go through it, and look at the state of the array after the while loop has finished.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i tried it but i dont have clue now. I will try it on Monday again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second swap in the partition function is there to place the pivot element in its correct sorted position in the array.

Once the loop in the partition function finishes, it means that i and j have crossed each other, and the elements to the left of j are less than or equal to the pivot, while the elements to the right of j are greater than the pivot.

However, the pivot element is still at array[links]. To place the pivot in its correct sorted position, you need to swap it with the element at index j. After this swap, the pivot element is at its correct position, and all elements to the left of it are smaller or equal, and all elements to the right are greater.

Answer (score 0):

Yes have to do the last `swap()`, because you return `j` - is the first element of the second half (which is higher than pivot element). The pivot element is the first one `arr[0]`, so you shoul move it to the end of the first path.

```java
private static int partition(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    // A
    int i = lo, j = hi;
    int v = arr[lo];

    while (i <= j) {
        if (arr[i] <= v) i++;
        else if (arr[j] > v) j--;
        else swap(arr, ++i, --j);
    }
    
    // B
    swap(arr, lo, j);
    
    // C
    return j;
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

`step A: [7, 6, 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 11, 1, 2, 18, 11, 4, 5, 17, 20, 25, 3, 8, 16]`, the pivot elemnt is `arr[0] = 7`, so we have to move all elements `<= 7` to the left part, and `> 7` -  to the right. And return the index of the first element of the right part.

`step B: [7, 6, 1, 3, 5, 10, 25, 4, 1, 2, 18, 11, 11, 5, 17, 20, 15, 3, 8, 16]`, the `j = 9 => arr[9] = 2`. So you either should do `j++`, but this is dangerout, in case `j = arr.length -1`. Or do not change it and `swap(arr, 0, 9)`.

`step C: [2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 10, 25, 4, 1, 7, 18, 11, 11, 5, 17, 20, 15, 3, 8, 16]`